# VB 2010 Crystal reports TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

Project originally started on VS 2005 upgraded in VS 2010.  Still targeting .net 2.0.
Crystal reports no longer display and give the following error:
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an exception.
with inner errors:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' threw an exception.
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

I have changed the target platform from AnyCPU to x86 and uninstalled/reinstalled Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, still getting the errors.

Any ideas?

TIA,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you shifted your project from VS 05 to VS 10. So In this case have you tried to build the reports again.
It happens sometime just give a try to one of your crystal report in new form and see.

Comment: I tried that and and it did not work.  Also, the problem was first noticed with a new report and form I just created in VS 2010.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If you noticed visual studio works with .net framework 4, and you told the error is targeting .net framework 2.0. So you could change your Visual studio settings to .net framework 2.0. If it doesn't picks 2.0 for your promoted project.

Comment: You might be using the crystal report(Software) that would not be compatible with the one you used in VS 05.  Or.  Change the settings as i told you.  The name of Crystal report that I use is SAP(http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: Can you send your project just for modification?